# How to export GCP image to bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I just tried to make an image and copy it by [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) into bucket.
After copying I tried to restore an image and run VM instance based on it, but it doesn't work.
Is there any ideas how to export images directly to Google Storage Bucket and successfully restore onto the VM instance.
Thanks.

Comment: What error do you receive? Or, what do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Actually I found a my bad about fstab (system tries to mount non-existed disks), also I can't connect to some nodes by SSH, but I'm also trying to fix this moment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problems you're having? Like error messages, what exactly isn't working, what you are trying to do to solve these problems...